# Can I increase timeout length with devtools::install_github()

Tags: r, devtools

Is there an option to increase the timeout length when using the `devtools::install_github()` command? I can't seem to find one when I `?install_github()`.

Comment: in the install.packages documentation:

> Timeouts

> A limit on the elapsed time for each call to R CMD INSTALL (so for source installs) can be set via environment variable _R_INSTALL_PACKAGES_ELAPSED_TIMEOUT_: in seconds (or in minutes or hours with optional suffix m or h, suffix s being allowed for the default seconds) with 0 meaning no limit.

Comment: Any chance to get this in an answer format?

Answer (score 0):

Timeout can be changed in global environment using e.g.

```
options(timeout=600)
```